# Outputing css grid through js is differant than normal grid?

Tags: javascript, css, grid

So i have usual grid and everyhting works properly. But then i output some of the html through this:

```
const outputHtml = matches => {
if (matches.length > 0) {
const html = matches
  .map(
    match => `
    <div class="rec">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="boxtop"><img src="${match.picture}" alt="1" /></div>
      <div class="boxbot"><p>${match.title}</p></div>
    </a>
    </div>`).join("");

matchList.innerHTML = html;
}};
```

Everything appears in a single column and i cannot set height of .rec.
CSS:

```
.receptai {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
 padding: 10px;
 }
.match-list > .rec {
 max-height: 200px;
 }
 .boxtop {
 position: relative;
 height: 80%;
 width: 100%;
 }
 .boxtop img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 }
 .boxbot {
 position: relative;
 height: 20%;
 background: var(--c2);
 color: var(--c1);
 }
```

Html:

```
<div class="receptai">
  <div id="match-list"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There’s no css for grid here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox just made edit. The problem is that everthing from js is going to a single match-list div. I assume this is the reason why everything is in single column.

Comment: There isn’t an element with the class name “receptai” being output by the JS.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ok now i added evertyhing.

Comment: Which element do you expect to be in columns?

Comment: @evolutionxbox every single .rec goes into single column i wish them to show as a grid in rows you know.

Comment: It’s because you have match-list in the way

Comment: Hmmm ye i see i tried just apply grid to match-list now but tottaly broke everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to add your inner div with 'rec' class inside the 'match-list' div and not the 'receptai' div. So it's not displayed as a grid since 'match-list' is just an element of the 'receptai' grid.
You should set the innerHTML directly to the 'receptai' div or style the 'match-list' as a grid itself, as show in the below snippet:

```js
matches = [
{
  title : "Merry",
  src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/15/13/58/christmas-4697165_960_720.jpg"
},
{
  title : "Christmas",
  src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/12/15/13/58/christmas-4697165_960_720.jpg"
}
]


const html = matches
  .map(
    match => `
    <div class="rec">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="boxtop"><img src="${match.src}" alt="1" /></div>
      <div class="boxbot"><p>"${match.title}"</p></div>
    </a>
    </div>`).join("");
let matchList = document.getElementById('match-list');
matchList.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
 #match-list {
   display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
    padding: 10px;
 }
#match-list > .rec {
 max-height: 200px;
 }
 .boxtop {
 position: relative;
 height: 80%;
 width: 100%;
 }
 .boxtop img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: block;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 }
 .boxbot {
 position: relative;
 height: 20%;
 background: var(--c2);
 color: var(--c1);
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="receptai">
  <div id="match-list"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes thank you and big thanks for the @evolutionxbox he suggested the same.